# Finite-state transducer to accept $i$'th word of DFA

Tags: finite-automata, transducers

If I have a DFA $D$ that accepts some regular language $L$, is it possible to construct some finite-state transducer $T$ that takes in an index $i$, and puts out the $i$'th word in $L$, ordered lexicographically?

I know from [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7247871/) paper that you can construct such a transducer that maps from a given word in $L$ to the next word in $L$, but the paper only briefly mentions the variant of the problem where an index is given instead.

Comment: What kind of transducer do you have in mind? Clearly it cannot be a letter-by-letter transducer, even if your input represents the index in unary.

Comment: @Shaull I was assuming/allowing non-deterministic transducers, i.e. with e-transitions. If this is non-standard I can edit the question.

Comment: There are lots of transducer models, so it would be good if you add the definition to the question. But my point actually was that this kind of transducer will inevitably need memory - it must count the index you give it, otherwise it cannot know even the first letter to output before the input is done.

Comment: Good point; I would accept this as an answer.

Comment: Let's see if better answers come up.

Comment: First of all, the paper is about words *of a specific length*. Otherwise lexicographic order is problematic, since it need not be isomorphic to $\omega$ (consider for example $0^*+1^*$, which is isomorphic to $\omega + \omega$).

Comment: Second, while you expect two adjacent words in the list of words in the language to be similar, making a transducer natural, there is no reason to expect any such connected between the index and the word it refers to, making your goal quite unnatural.

Comment: What might be interesting is *ranking/unranking*, that is, *any* algorithm that given $n,i$ produces the $i$'th word of length $n$ in lexicographic order, as well as the algorithm for the inverse: given a word $w$ in the language, compute $n,i$. This can be done using standard counting techniques.